# What do these various descriptions mean in a dobutamine stress echocardiogam report?

Tags: heart-disease, myocardial-infarction

- Evidence of inferior/posterior infarction or hibernation
- Preserved LVEF Basal posterior segment is akinetic
- Basal and mid inferior segments are hypokinetic
- Preserved systolic function
- No pericardial effusion

Comment: Is it safe to assume these descriptions are from an echocardiogram conducted on you? If so, you need to direct your question to the doctor who ordered the exam.